# negative numbers in red tkinter and pandastable

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I would like to change the color of negative numbers to red but I can't find anything in the documenation that works.

```
import pandastable as pt
import tkinter as tk 
import pandas as pd

window = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(window)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)
d = {'col1':[1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 5], 'col2':[1, -0.5, -1, 4, 2, -2]
    ,'col3': [-0.345, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
pt = pt.Table(frame1, dataframe = df, width=300, height=300, rows=8, cols=8)
pt.show()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have no idea what a mask is but seems it is kinda what You need take a look at the docs: https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pandastable/core.html#Table.setColorByMask

Comment: yes but that's changing only the cell color and not the color of the font. Maybe I got it wrong I don't know

Comment: I've been reading through the docs and I'm still not sure how to do it but [this Github issue](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable/issues/70) may be of use.